# BCP is not working if first column is empty

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I have source file in which 90% of first field is empty. I want to load this file to SQL server table with BCP utility. When i run BCP command, BCP utility is not able to recognize or distinguish records.
My Source file has data as below.

`|100168|27238800000|14750505|1|273
|100168|27238800000|14750505|1|273
|100681|88392930052|37080101|1|252
|101014|6810000088|90421505|12|799
|101595|22023000000|21050510|8|780`

I am using

```
 **bcp [DBNAME].[dbo].[TABLE1] in \\filelocation\filename -e \\filelocation\filename_Error.txt -c -t | -S ServerName -T -h TABLOCK -m 1**
```

I am getting error message in error.txt

> as #@ Row 1, Column 28: String data, right truncation @#    100168  27238800000 14750505    1   273
>     100168|27238800000|14750505|1|273. Here BCP is not able to recognize
>   records. Due to this BCP is trying loaded next record data into last
>   field which is causing data truncation.

Table schema is

```
CREATE TABLE [DBO].[TABLE1](  
FLD1 VARCHAR(10)  
,FLD2 VARCHAR(10)  
,FLD3 VARCHAR(22)  
,FLD4 VARCHAR(15)  
,FLD5 VARCHAR(10)  
,FLD6 VARCHAR(12) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the pipe. Pipe (character |) is used for redirecting standard output for command lines

The following simplified line works with your sample

`bcp.exe [db].dbo.[table1] in "path\Data.dat" -S".\instance" -T -c -t"|"`

I omitted the error limit `-m`, log `-e` and table lock hint `-h`, but those should not affect the import, but if you still have an issue try quoting parameters like the server name and filenames

I used a text file with standard `\r\n` row terminators as expected by `-c`